# Counting words using awk

Tags: unix

I want to count total occurence of the exact word "month" in the given input independent of case using awk command :

```
I have to pay the MONTHLY fees
This Month it is gonna be difficult
Every month is same
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: What is the expected result in that case ? 2 or 3 ? ( does the word 'monthly' count or not ? )

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'IGNORECASE = 1;{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i == "month") c++} END {print c}' file.txt
```